# CI merchant codeigniter library paypal checkout issues

Tags: codeigniter, ci-merchant

I am using Ci merchant in my codeigniter , but i got this error , can u please mention what should i do ?

> public function mypaypal()    {       echo "mypaypal";    }
>
> public function cancel()    {       echo "cancelled";   }
>
> public function index()     {
>
> ```
>     $this->load->library('merchant');
>     $this->merchant->load('paypal_express');
>     $settings = array(
>                   'username' => '******',
>                   'password' => '******',
>                   'signature' => '********',
>                   'test_mode' => true
>                   );
>
>     $this->merchant->initialize($settings);
>
>     $params = array(
>       'amount' => 1.00,
>       'currency' => 'USD',
>       'return_url' => base_url().'mypaypal',
>       'cancel_url' => base_url().'cancel');
>
>     $response = $this->merchant->purchase($params);
>     var_dump($response);
>
>     if ($response->success())             {
>
>           var_dump($response);            }           else            {
>           $message = $response->message();
>           echo('Error processing payment: ');
>           exit;           }
>
>       }
> ```

and i got this error :

> object(Merchant_response)#17 (8) { ["_status":protected]=> string(6)
>   "failed" ["_message":protected]=> string(51) "Problem with the SSL CA
>   cert (path? access rights?)" ["_reference":protected]=> NULL
>   ["_data":protected]=> NULL ["_redirect_url":protected]=> NULL
>   ["_redirect_method":protected]=> string(3) "GET"
>   ["_redirect_message":protected]=> NULL ["_redirect_data":protected]=>
>   NULL }

Answer (score 0):

> Problem with the SSL CA cert (path? access rights?)

Your server doesn't have a root SSL certificate set up correctly (it uses this to verify that outgoing connections are connecting to the right server).

I recommend using [Omnipay](https://github.com/adrianmacneil/omnipay) (the successor to CI-Merchant), as this uses [Guzzle](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle) for HTTP connections, which comes bundled with the latest root SSL certificate so you don't need to worry about your server having them installed.